# VisualBasic inputbox in c# - multidimensional array output

Tags: c#, vb.net

So,

Im trying to get my inputbox to prompt a user to enter a week (between 1-4, as int) and a day (between Mon-Fri, as string) and then it goes into my array and outputs that index into a textbox. 
Im coding this in c# and using windows form application.

My code is as follows:

```
txtOutput.Text += "Filling the array with user input..." + "\r\n";
txtOutput.Text += "The product allocation is as follows:" + "\r\n";

        string[,] toys = new string[5, 4];
        for (int week = 0; week <= 3; week++)
        {
            for (int day = 0; day <= 4; day++)
            {
                toys[day, week] = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter value for Day " + Convert.ToString(day + 1) + " in week " + Convert.ToString(week + 1) + ".");
            }
        }

txtOutput.Text += "\t\t" + "Mon" + "\t" + "Tue" + "\t" + "Wed" + "\t" + "Thu" + "\t" + "Fri" + "\t" + "\r\n";

        for (int week = 0; week <= 3; week++)
        {              
            txtOutput.Text += "Week " + (week + 1) + "\t";
            for (int day = 0; day <= 4; day++)
            {
                txtOutput.Text += toys[day, week];
                if (day != 4)
                {
                    txtOutput.Text += "\t";
                }
            }
            txtOutput.Text += "\r\n";
        }
```

This basically makes my array, gathers all the info, stores it, outputs it, now i am trying to get my input box to prompt a certain day/week and then output that.

Was thinking i would use this line and then work around it?

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter value for Day " + Convert.ToString(day + 1) + " in week " + Convert.ToString(week + 1) + ".");
```

**QUESTION**

Im trying to make the visualbasic inputbox ask the user to input a day and a week, and then it goes to my array, finds the value and outputs it to my textbox.

Comment: Using InputBox in VB is bad enough but using it in C# is an abomination. I'm begging you to create your own dialogue.  Anyway, I'm not really sure what you're asking.  Does that line of code do what you want and, if not, how does it differ?  You really ought to look at String.Format too.

Comment: Have to use it as part of a course im learning, kinda sucks because its hard to figure out how to get it to work the way i need it to. I added the question to the bottom

Answer (score 1):

There's no C# equivalent. You have two options: create a custom Form or reference VisualBasic and call InputBox.

Comment: @ivowilbo, I have referenced Visualbasic already :) im just trying to figure out a way to use that inputbox to search my array for a specific day/wk and output the value

Comment: Ok, try to be more specific in your question as it's not clear what you want.

Comment: @ivowilbo, added the question to the end, sorry for being all over the place

Comment: And what is the problem you are getting? InputBox only let you ask one value?

Comment: I can get it to get the value i want, my main problem is figuring out how to get it to search the array at a certain spot.

Comment: From that last description this has nothing to do with InputBox.  It doesn't search an array at all.  Basically all your issue is that you need to get an appropriate array element in a nested loop.  The fact that that array element is going to go into a String that will be used as a prompt on an InputBox is a complete red herring.  Now that you've taken out the original question we have even less information.  How about you try providing a FULL and CLEAR description of the ACTUAL issue?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than typing in values why not have two dropdowns. 1st dropdown with values 1-4 and second values Mon-Fri.